# How to set a fixed scale to a layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I have a polygon layer in ArcMap. To full extent the scale is 1:35,000. It only fits in a 210cm x 160cm page. I want to fix the scale to 1:10,000 and make it fit to a 84.1cm x 59.4. Is there a way to do it in ArcGIS 10.1?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like is not possible to view the entire polygon at the larger scale (1:10,000) and fit within a smaller area (~84x59"). The only option is to use a smaller scale or a larger area. That is just the fundamental nature of scale.

Answer (score 0):

the size of the page will not adjust to the layer's extent. You first need to go in the file> [page and print settings](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sm00000003000000) to change the page size (uncheck "use printer setting if needed), and then you can fix the scale.

There are two ways to fix the scale : write the new scale in the [box](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?Topicname=Setting_the_map_scale) that display the scale, or go to the dataframe properties where you can really fix a scale (the zoom tools are then disabled).

Comment: I have already done that and it doesn't work. To be exact it zooms in and only a part of the layer is visible.

Comment: now that I look again at your number, what you ask is not possible. If it is at full extent 1/35000, you need a LARGER paper size to show it at 1/10000 (210 *3.5 , 160 * 3.5). I first thought you meant 1/100,000